# Fluid simulation restarts randomly

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am a beginner, so I'm just learning how to make fluid simulations in  blender. I have a fluid simulation with a domain, 3 effectors, and the inflow, which has 2 keyframes, one at the start and one at the end. The keyframes are for the use infow checkbox, the first one with use inflow on, and the second with use inflow off. I moved the inflow off keyframe from 40 to another place (I forget, somewhere between 40 - 60 exclusive), and then to frame 60. But, when I play the simulation, at frame 47, it stops and restarts (goes back to where there was only a little fluid in the scene). It also restarted at frame 53. Help! I am using blender 2.82a, and Windows.

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mlmLsOfclxOvEghPIv5HvV3vIm8Scqf1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: why your effectors are "turned off"?

Answer (score 1):

I see from your file that you are not using the cache. Switch to modular type (under DOMAIN > physics properties > cache) and every time you change something, clear the cache and recalculate it (using the CACHE button under domain > settings).

try this and share your feedback

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the bake data button? Because I don't see a cache button under the settings.

Comment: check the screenshot